# PHP PHAR having problems with filenames with multiple dots

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to extract some files out of a `tar.gz` file.

But the filename seems to cause problems:

```
xxx.some-random-number.tar.gz
```

When I use `\PharData::isValidPharFilename('xxx.some-random-number.tar.gz', false)` the function returns false. When I omit the first part `(i.e. \PharData::isValidPharFilename('some-random-number.tar.gz', false)` it returns true.

I can't use different filenames as they are provided from a third-party service (and I don't wanna rename them on the fly, either (tedious).

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the extension needs to be phar, tar or zip.  I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59693155/773849) where I provided a bit more detail.