# Include PHP PHAR without .phar extension

Tags: php, include, require, phar

I'm having trouble including a PHAR into my application bootstrapping code. I'm attempting to include the `phpunit/phpunit` PHAR to have the PHPUnit classes available in my application.

Given I have the following directory structure:

```
/path/to/code/
    app.php
    phpunit
```

Where `phpunit` is the PHPUnit as a PHAR, and `app.php` contains:

```php
<?php

$phar = 'phar://' . __DIR__ . '/phpunit';

include $phar;

assert(class_exists('\\PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase'));
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  include(phar:///path/to/code/phpunit): failed to open stream:
    phar error: no directory in "phar:///path/to/code/phpunit",
    must have at least phar:///path/to/code/phpunit/ for root directory
    (always use full path to a new phar) in /path/to/code/app.php on line 4
```

But when I rename the PHAR to `phpunit.phar`, and include that instead using

```php
<?php

$phar = 'phar://' . __DIR__ . '/phpunit.phar';

include $phar;

assert(class_exists('\\PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase'));
```

The code works fine, and the `TestCase` class exists.

Why doesn't the first version work, and what does the error about "full path to a new phar" mean?

---

My PHP version is 7.2, and the PHPUnit PHAR is on version 7.* which has been installed with Phive.

---

**"Why don't you just include using the `.phar` extension?"**

I want to be able to use the PHPUnit PHAR as a binary without the `.phar` extension to keep things cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Omit using the `phar://` stream since you're accessing the (outer) Phar file. Using `phar://` actually tries to access resources inside a Phar archive.

```
<?php
$phar = __DIR__ . '/phpunit';
include $phar;
assert(class_exists('\\PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't the first version work

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/62826e95d22e9e0db298a476636b996bce49c295/ext/phar/phar.c#L1898), you should be able to use a mark the phar as executable and use it without an extension, but if you do that, I am not sure you can run it.

```
 * if executable is 1, only returns SUCCESS if the extension is one of the tar/zip .phar extensions
 * if executable is 0, it returns SUCCESS only if the filename does *not* contain ".phar" anywhere, and treats
 * the first extension as the filename extension
 *
 * if an extension is found, it sets ext_str to the location of the file extension in filename,
 * and ext_len to the length of the extension.
 * for urls like "phar://alias/oops" it instead sets ext_len to -1 and returns FAILURE, which tells
 * the calling function to use "alias" as the phar alias
 *
 * the last parameter should be set to tell the thing to assume that filename is the full path, and only to check the
 * extension rules, not to iterate.
```

> what does the error about "full path to a new phar" mean?

I think they are trying to convey that you cannot pass a partial path to a phar.

> I want to be able to use the PHPUnit PHAR as a binary without the .phar extension to keep things cleaner.

You could always just symlink or alias the phar file to an extensionless name.